# Sparse Matrix, overloading= c++

Tags: c++

I need to overload `= operator` in my class SparseMatrix.

```
template <class T>
class SparseMatrix
{

  public:
  template <class T>
  class element
  {
  public:
      int x;
      int y;
      T val; 
      element(T war, int x1, int y1) { val = war; x = x1; y = y1; };
   };

  vector<element<T>> diff; //contains a cell with diffrent value
  T value; //contains a value of all cells at begining.
  int sizeX;
  int sizeY;

  SparseMatrix(T val, int x, int y) { value = val; sizeX = x; sizeY = y; };
  ~SparseMatrix() {};

  T& operator()(int t, int t1)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < diff.size(); x++)
    if (diff[x].x == t && diff[x].y == t1)
        return diff[x].val;
    return value;
  }
};
```

If I type `mat(1,1) = 5`, program make a new element with parameters `x=1`, `y=1`, `val=1` and push back this element in vector diff.

Comment: What's the actual question/problem?

Comment: [OT] the inner class `element` doesn't need to be template.

Comment: This sounds like homework, since all the necessary words are already in the question. The “push back” looks particularly like a typing instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you want to use this overloaded `operator=` in an expression like `mat(1,1) = 5` and not `mat = something`, you don't really want to overload the `operator=` for the matrix itself. Instead, make `operator()` return a proxy for which you will overload the operator:

```
template <class T>
class SparseMatrix
{

  //...

  struct Proxy
  {
    int t, t1;
    SparseMatrix &mat;

    Proxy(int t, int t1, SparseMatrix &mat) : t(t), t1(t1), mat(mat) {}

    operator T() const {
      for (int x = 0; x < mat.diff.size(); x++)
        if (mat.diff[x].x == t && mat.diff[x].y == t1)
          return mat.diff[x].val;
      return mat.value;
    }

    T& operator= (const T &v) {
      for (int x = 0; x < mat.diff.size(); x++)
        if (mat.diff[x].x == t && mat.diff[x].y == t1)
          return mat.diff[x].val = v;  //it exists, assign & return it
      // it doesn't exist, create new one
      mat.diff.push_back(element<T>(v, t, t1));
      return mat.diff.back().val;
    }
  };

  Proxy operator() (int t, int t1) {
    return Proxy(t, t1, *this);
  }
};
```

You can play around with const correctness, perfect forwarding, making `Proxy` noncopyable etc., but the basic idea is outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

actually you only need to update the overloading function for ()

```
T& operator()(int t, int t1)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < diff.size(); x++)
    {
        if (diff[x].x == t && diff[x].y == t1)
            return diff[x].val;
    }

    diff.push_back(element(value,t,t1));
    return diff.back().val;
}
```

Comment: yes, if the element is not in  the sparse matrix and we try to fetch the element by (i,j) it would insert a value ,so some protections is necessary